# Enviar formulário e apresentar mensagem de “sucesso” na própria página, e após clicar no submit aparecer outro botão

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Olá eu sou novo nessas coisas de códigos e queria saber como que eu faço para aparecer a mensagem de sucesso após eu dar Submit, eu quero aquelas mensagens que aparecem o campo verde, tipo uma div e edita com css. E eu também queria que após dar submit aparecer outro botão tipo um botão de download

Index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta "charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Cadastro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme.css" />
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!--Arquivo Ajax-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function() {
        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "newsletter-form.php",
          data: dados,
          success: function envio() {

            var cont = "Email enviado com sucesso";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = cont;
          }

        });

        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="for" <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">

          <form id="ajax_form" name="signup" method="post" action="cadastro.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name_user" class="form-control" name="nome" required placeholder="Seu nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" id="email_user" class="form-control" name="email" required placeholder="Seu email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="tel" id="telefone_user" class="form-control" name="telefone" required placeholder="Seu telefone" />
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-register">
Enviar
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar a mensagem em um caixa flutuante, você deve estar falando em criar um snackbar. No código abaixo, adicionei o snackbar e o botão de download. O botão de download carrega a página como oculto, e após o sucesso na requisição ajax, a classe de CSS que o torna oculto é removida pelo jquery e o botão de Enviar também é removido. O código fica mais ou menos assim:

```js
// Função responsável por mostrar e remover o snackbar
function snackbar() {
    // Get the snackbar DIV
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
    // Add the "show" class to DIV
    x.className = "show";
    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}

// Sua função que faz a requisição AJAX
jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
      jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function() {
        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "newsletter-form.php",
          data: dados,
          success: function envio() {
            // Mostra o snackbar na tela
            snackbar()
            // Mostra o botão de download
            $("#btnDownload").removeClass('hidden');
            // Remove o botão de enviar
            $("#btnEnviar").remove();
            var cont = "Email enviado com sucesso";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = cont;
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
```

```css
/* Classe para ocultar o botão de download */
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}


/* CSS do Snackbar */
/* The snackbar - position it at the bottom and in the middle of the screen */
#snackbar {
    visibility: hidden; /* Hidden by default. Visible on click */
    min-width: 250px; /* Set a default minimum width */
    margin-left: -125px; /* Divide value of min-width by 2 */
    background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
    color: #fff; /* White text color */
    text-align: center; /* Centered text */
    border-radius: 2px; /* Rounded borders */
    padding: 16px; /* Padding */
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the screen */
    z-index: 1; /* Add a z-index if needed */
    left: 50%; /* Center the snackbar */
    bottom: 30px; /* 30px from the bottom */
}

/* Show the snackbar when clicking on a button (class added with JavaScript) */
#snackbar.show {
    visibility: visible; /* Show the snackbar */

/* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar. 
However, delay the fade out process for 2.5 seconds */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

/* Animations to fade the snackbar in and out */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Cadastro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="for">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">

          <form id="ajax_form" name="signup" method="post" action="cadastro.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name_user" class="form-control" name="nome" required placeholder="Seu nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" id="email_user" class="form-control" name="email" required placeholder="Seu email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="tel" id="telefone_user" class="form-control" name="telefone" required placeholder="Seu telefone" />
            </div>
            <button id='btnEnviar' class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-register">    
Enviar</button>
            
            <button id='btnDownload' class="hidden btn btn-primary btn-block btn-register">Download</button>
            

<!-- Snackbar -->
<div id="snackbar">E-mail enviado.</div>
        
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado João, mas e os codigos javascript eu coloco onde?

Comment: Dentro da tag `<script>` que você estava utilizando mesmo. Embora, a medida que seu código for crescendo, seja interessante você utilizar um arquivo externo para o código JS e chamá-lo no html usando `<script src="arquivo.js"/>` por exemplo

Comment: cara eu clico no botão e não sai do lugar

Comment: Você conseguiu ao menos efetuar a requisição no servidor, i.e., enviar os dados? Se sim, o botão desapareceu e tudo mais? Você inseriu o CSS também? Quando eu testei por aqui - utilizando outro URL só pra conseguir passar a request - funcionou normalmente.

Comment: O botão não desapareceu, não sai do lugar eu clico no submit e não muda nada

Comment: Certo, mas a request passou ou não? Faz o seguinte, troca a linha `success: function envio() {` por `success: function envio(data) { console.log(data)` manda submit e vê se a request tá tendo sucesso. Junto a isso, adicione `type='submit'` no botão de enviar.

Comment: eu fiz isso mas nao teve mudança nenhuma, você tem whatss?c se tiver deixa o numero aqui que te chamo lá

Comment: Não sei como não esta indo, pq no seu deu certo e no meu não deu

Comment: Estranho. Você fez isso que eu disse e não apareceu nada no console? Se não apareceu, por algum motivo a request não tá passando, ou então não está sendo chamada.

Comment: Apareceu esse erro no console 
POST http://localhost/Notflix2/php/nueva/newsletter-form.php 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ config.js:15
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: O erro está na requisição. Ele está te retornando que a página não existe. Esse é realmente o URL da api que você está fazendo a requisição?

Comment: Eu mudei e diz que enviou com sucesso o email, mas no console aparece esse erro                                                                                                                
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Object.envio [as success] ((index):40)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
envio @ (index):40
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
x @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: Mas a mensagem apareceu "Email enviado"

Comment: É porque você a div com id `msg` não existe. Mas de resto, tudo normal.

Comment: Oxe, quem ja viu? kkk e eu faço o que?

Comment: Pode apagar essas duas linhas: `var cont = "Email enviado com sucesso"; document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = cont;`

Comment: Agora funcionou cara haha vlw cara você merece tudo

Comment: Marca a thread como respondida aí ;)